# How to use secret from vault in kubernetes ingress tls

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to configure Ingress resource tls (I am using Ngninx ingress) with certificate from Hashicorp Vault. I saw that you can do it using vault-csi-provider. The issue is that I can not use image for that in my company (security reasons).

Do you know of any other way I can do it? I saw that people are using cert-manager for that, however I am not auto-updating certificates right now (I just have a cert file in Vault which I want to use in my Ingress)

Comment: Do you have option to use projects like [External Secrets](https://external-secrets.io/v0.7.2/) or [Vault Secrets Operator](https://github.com/ricoberger/vault-secrets-operator)? With those you can get secret from `vault`, create k8s `Secret` object and then use it with `ingress`. If that is not possible you can create k8s `Service Account`, add proper permissions to `vault` so it will be able to get secret and then create k8s `Job` with some whitelisted image that will create needed k8s `secret` in namespace where you have your `ingress` resource.

Comment: Looks like I should be able to use Vault Secrets Operator. I will check this out. Thanks